# Convert problem to linear programming task

Tags: linear-programming

I have function $\max \{ |x-1| + 2|y-1| | x,y \in R, x+y \leq 2 \}$. Can this problem be converted to LP? I think it cant because of the abs. value in criterial function, but Im not sure.

If it can, how to convert it? I think that restrictive conditions are already in correct form so I only have to convert criterial function to some form without abs. if its possible.. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Would converting it to 4 LP's work? $\max{x−1+2y−1}$ subject to $x+y≤2, x-1≥0, y-1≥0$, $\max{-x+1+2y−1}$ subject to $x+y≤2, x-1≤0, y-1≥0$, etc.? Then just take whichever is biggest as your solution?

Comment: So you suggest dividing the equation into four different with corresponding restrictions? I dont know if its LP after that but maybe youre right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be converted into LP. Use the following hint

Hint: $|z|$ can be replaced by $z^{+}+z^{-}$ along with the conditions $z^{+}\geq 0, z^{-}\geq 0$.

Comment: but what if $|z|$ is in criterial function and not in restrictions???

Comment: @Smajl: You replace $|z|$ by $z^++z^-$ in the criterial function as well.